# Send a TCP / IP message AKKA actor

Tags: java, scala, tcp, akka, actor

Is it possible to send a message over TCP / IP to an AKKA actor?

For example, write a client like:

```
mySocket = new Socket("theactor", 75);
os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("HELLO");
```

That could send messages to AKKA actor?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating a little more on Viktor’s response, the minimal example would be

```
import akka.actor._
import ActorDSL._
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

object Server extends App {
  implicit val sys = ActorSystem("telnet")

  actor(new Act with ActorLogging {
    IOManager(context.system) listen new InetSocketAddress(1234)
    become {
      case IO.NewClient(server) ⇒
        server.accept()
      case IO.Read(handle, bytes) ⇒
        log.info("got {} from {}", bytes.decodeString("utf-8"), handle)
    }
  })
}
```

Then in a different shell start `telnet localhost 1234` and start typing, you’ll see one actor log message per line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and no. You'll have to use Akka IO module or Akka Camel module (with netty or mina component):

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io.html

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/camel.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send a message across a remote actor using IP, Why don't you try the Akka Remote Actor system? ["Read it here"](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html)